# Address bar URL gets changed on Validation failure in Spree Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, spree

I've just overridden `views/spree/user_registations/new.html.erb` and added my contents in this file.

when I hit `localhost:3000/` I get my custom form.

On validation failure case it's rendering the action `'new'`.

Next, after validation failure the  `'new'` action section gets rendered & I  get the view.

But in the browser address, I get  "`http://localhost:3000/spree/signup`".

I want it to be `localhost:3000/` only.

How can we achieve this and see only `localhost:3000/` in address bar on validation failure ?

```
#routes.rb : 
  root to: 'spree/user_registrations#new', as: '/'
```

This is my View Section :

```
#spree/user_registrations/new.html.erb 

<%= form_for @user,  url:  spree.registration_path(@user),  id: 'user_new'   do |f| %> 

<span> <%= f.text_field :email, :placeholder => "Email *", name: 'email' %>
<span> <%= f.password_field :password, name: 'password' %></span>
<span> <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation name: 'password_confirmation' %></span>

<% end %>
```

Controller :

```
    Spree::UserRegistrationsController.class_eval do
        def new
        @user = Spree::User.new
        end

       def create
             @user = Spree::User.new(email: params[:email], password: params[:password], password_confirmation: params[:password_confirmation])

                    if @user.save
                        session[:customer_id] = @user.id
                        set_current_user(@user.id)
                        redirect_to main_app.profile_dashboards_path  and return
                    else
                        render 'new'
                    end
                end
        end

end
```